# Hidden Communities indicated despite the account being deleted

Tags: bug, profile-page, hidden-communities

I have just noticed on my Chemistry (and other) profiles that it is stated that I have '1 hidden community' (as shown below):

[image]

This *was* true, until I had m membership at that site deleted a little while ago (2 days at the time of writing this question).

When I go to the list (by clicking 'edit list'), it is shown correctly that there are no hidden communities (as I had earlier had my membership there deleted):

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Hmm, how long is that *deleted **a while ago***? Just making sure caching is not to blame on this one.

Comment: The account was deleted two days ago - will edit that in

Comment: Closing this one as a duplicate since the account is gone and there's no example to look at for debugging here anymore.