# Profile is still counting a hidden community that no longer exists

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, hidden-communities

I had a profile on a private beta site a while back that I listed under my Hidden Communities so it wouldn't show up on my profile on other sites. The private beta was closed, but my profile is still showing that I have 1 hidden community, both on [my Profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865899/abby-hairboat?tab=profile):

[image]

...and on [my Activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865899/abby-hairboat?tab=topactivity):

[image]

But by going to `/users/hidecommunities/[me]` I can see that there isn't actually anything hidden anymore:

[image]

(By instinct I want to blame caching, but it's been several months.)

Comment: Related - maybe even a duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261595/hidden-communities-indicated-despite-the-account-being-deleted

Comment: I think so but @Animuson decided to dupe vote it the other way around...

Comment: @rene It's because my circles are *freehand*.

Comment: `Closing this one as a duplicate since the account is gone and there's no example to look at for debugging here anymore.` Congrats, you are now a guinea pig by process of elimination.

Comment: It's the sexualitity site right?

Comment: @abby but your circles are not red.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has now been fixed, but you knew that already. :-)